# How to extract multi-part zip files with PHP?

Tags: php, zip, extract

How to extract a multi-part zip file with PHP? Is it possible?

Comment: this is different.(extract two part)

Comment: Read the manual of `ZipArchive` !!

Comment: I search all questions but nothings found.my problem is extract a large file that zipped in multi part.

Comment: See above: _one solution is just to run console commands in PHP_ `:)`.

Comment: This question is different from the one mentioned above, as it's about multipart zip archive, here is related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989863/multi-part-zip-in-php and the only answer I could found is the example of xZip class found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php#112195

Comment: This question asks how to extract a zip which was split into several parts. The linked "duplicate" question asks how to unzip in php. The other question doesn't even contain an answer with the keyword "multi"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409672/how-to-extract-multi-part-zip-files-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1